# Function with infinite maxima and minima

Tags: functions, special-functions

Can you please give an example of a function with an infinite number of maxima and minima occurring in any finite time interval?

Edit: This question came to me as I was reading on the dirichlet conditions for the fourier transform of a function $g(t)$ to exist. Given that $g(t)$ is a non-periodic and deterministic signal, one of the conditions is that $g(t)$ be a single-valued function, with a finite number of maxima and minima in any finite time interval. Hence the question.

Comment: $f(x)=1$ when $x \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1)$ and $f(x)=0$ for remaining values in $[0,1)$. Then extend it periodically.

Comment: Strict max/min or not? (If not, any constant function works). Does it have to be continuous? Context, please.

Comment: Related: [Construction of a noncommon continuous real function](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/70211)

Answer (score 2):

Let $\chi_{\Bbb Q}(x):=1 $ if $x \in \Bbb Q$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Or just $f(x)=0$, even simpler.